# "How to open one's Word application with a file through the browser using PHP HTML CSS?

Tags: php, html, ms-word, office365, href

I am encountering an issue in the context of a web application project using PHP, JAVASCRIPT, MYSQL technologies with a web server hosted on OVH.

The OVH server allows storage of various types of files: PDF, images, docx (Word).

The website (web application developed in PHP) displays files on an HTML page in the style of a file explorer (e.g., Windows Explorer).

The user should be able to open a docx file in Word from the HTML page displaying the files in a folder.

My latest attempt uses the following HTML code:

`<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|{{ filepath }}">{{ document }}</a>`

The error returned is as follows:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2iqO.png)

I have tried several methods. First, I tried opening the file with the winword command. Then, I attempted to open it with an HTML link "not_blank" to open the file in a different tab. To address the error, I tried removing my site from the list of sensitive sites, but without success. I don't fully understand this principle. I also tried checking all the boxes for blocked files in Word options. I want to emphasize that the project is using HTTPS.

Could you guide me or help me resolve this error, which I've been stuck on for a week?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a translation of the error message please? Because you've provided it as an image rather than copy/pasting the text into your question, I can't run Google translate on it.

Comment: _"I tried removing my site from the list of sensitive sites, but without success"_ - meaning what, you were not able to change the zone for the site, or it did not have any effect? The error message indeed appears to be talking about that concept of "Security Zones" Windows has, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/per-site-configuration-by-policy#windows-security-zones, but I can't tell any details from the French wording either.

Comment: Sorry for that, error said : To protect you from unsecured content, Office has blocked the opening of this file because it originates from a sensitive site zone. Thank you for your attention